# Laravel access data posted from React app

Tags: reactjs, post, axios, laravel-8

I am posting data to Laravel from React using axios

```
user.authenticateUser(authDetails, {
      onSuccess: data => {       
         axios.post('/formSubmit', {
            data: data
        })
        .then(function (response) {
            console.log(response.data);
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            console.log(error);
        });
        
        console.log("onSuccess:", data);
      },
```

In Laravel controller

```
public static function formSubmit(Request $request)
    {

     return $request->all();
    }
```

In Laravel routes

```
Route::post('formSubmit','MyController@formSubmit');

Route::get('formSubmit','MyController@formSubmit');
```

My post is successful, so in

console.log(response.data)

i can see the data

But how can i echo out (use) this data in Laravel?
I need to pass this data to another public function in "MyController"

Answer (score 0):

Try to put code before `console.log(response.data)`. This means that you have to store response.data in a variable and then use this variable of data as a parameter to another function in your controller.

I attach a helpful link with [axios and laravel](https://blastcoding.com/en/axios-and-laravel/).